# Python Split() function splitting for no apparent reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I have a problem with the split() function, for some reason it splits somewhere that isn't the separator ",". I'm reading a comma separated file filled with genes and some attributes. but when i read this line from the file

G234064,Essential,GTP/GDP-exchange factors (GEFs),Translation complexes,?,PS00824,1,CELLULAR ORGANIZATION (proteins are localized to the corresponding organelle),cytoplasm.

but instead of splitting into 9 different items in a list it splits into these 10:

```
['G240504',
  'Non-Essential',
  '?',
  '?',
  'Sensitivity to aminoacid analogs and other drugs',
  'PS00868',
  '12',
  'CELLULAR ORGANIZATION (proteins are localized to the corresponding '
  'organelle)',
  'cytoplasm.']
```

I couldn't find anyone with similar problems, this is the code i used

```
def main():
    file = open("Genes_relation.data.txt")
    readfile = file.readlines()
    genlist = []
    for list in readfile:
        genlist.append(list.rstrip("\n").split(","))
```

I expect the output to be

```
['G240504',
  'Non-Essential',
  '?',
  '?',
  'Sensitivity to aminoacid analogs and other drugs',
  'PS00868',
  '12',
  'CELLULAR ORGANIZATION (proteins are localized to the corresponding 
   organelle)',
  'cytoplasm.']
```

Does anyone understand what's going on?

Comment: The line in the question body is not the same line as in the code.

Comment: "but instead of splitting into 9 different items in a list it splits into these 10"-- there are only 9 items there, there is no comma at the end of the line `corresponding '`

Comment: Can you put your actual input also here, and not just the expected output. It helps to understand the context better.

Comment: Have a look **very closely** at your output. It has 9 elements, not 10. There's no `,` after `corresponding '`. E.g. this `['foo' 'bar']` is the same as `['foobar']`. I don't know how exactly you obtained that output but it has 9 elements, not 10. The formatting is just misleading. The best way to verify it is to print length after split.

Comment: How do you display the output? Neither writing to a file nor printing to a terminal will display a string as two strings that would be joined as a literal.

Comment: How did you make sure it's actually the `split()` and not a newline after `corresponding` in the file you read?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi This is how `pprint.pprint(lst)` would display it

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your error, but I am not able. You have to check coding in your file, maybe there are some unexpected commas or maybe the coding is wrong. Sometimes in biological data there is different encoding and this causes different unexpected behaviours. I am not able to do anything more for you.

```
>>> x = "G234064,Essential,GTP/GDP-exchange factors (GEFs),Translation complexes,?,PS00824,1,CELLULAR ORGANIZATION (proteins are localized to the corresponding organelle),cytoplasm"
>>> x.split(',')
['G234064', 
'Essential', 
'GTP/GDP-exchange factors (GEFs)', 
'Translation complexes', 
'?', 
'PS00824', 
'1', 
'CELLULAR ORGANIZATION (proteins are localized to the corresponding organelle)',
 'cytoplasm']
```